# Migrating from Moment to Luxon - (t) => moment(t).format('hh:mm') equivalent

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, luxon

I'm migrating an old piece of code from Moment to Luxon and bumped into the function below:

```js
export const TIME_FORMATTER = {
  HOUR: (t) => moment(t).format('hh:mm'),
  DAY: (t) => moment(t).format('M/DD'),
  HOUR_PERIOD: (t) => moment(t).format('hh:mm A'),
  DAY_HOUR_PERIOD: (t) => moment(t).format('hh:mm A M/DD'),
  SEC: (t) => moment(t).format('HH:mm:ss')
};
```

which gets called as follows:

```js
export const getFormatterByTimeInterval = (timeInterval: number) => {
  if (timeInterval <= 240) {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.DAY_HOUR_PERIOD;
  }
  else if (timeInterval > 480) {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.HOUR_PERIOD;
  }
  else {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.DAY;
  }
}
```

My initial thought was to use the same call format with Luxon:

```js
const TIME_FORMATTER_LUXON = {
  HOUR: (t) => DateTime.local(t).toFormat("hh:mm"),
  DAY: (t) => DateTime.local(t).toFormat("M/d"),
  HOUR_PERIOD: (t) => DateTime.local(t).toFormat("t"),
  DAY_HOUR_PERIOD: (t) => DateTime.local(t).toFormat("t M/d"),
  SEC: (t) => DateTime.local(t).toFormat("HH:mm:ss")
};
```

This gets called on another file `const formatter = getFormatterByTimeInterval(timeInterval);` but it's returning `Invalid DateTime`

Is this possible with Luxon? What can be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like your old code might have a few issues, so I want to at least address them before responding to your question:

The only function signature for `moment` which accepts a `number` argument is [Unix Timestamp (milliseconds)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/):

> Similar to `new Date(Number)`, you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of *milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).
>
> ```js
> const day = moment(1318781876406);
> ```
>
> [Note: ECMAScript calls this a "Time Value"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range)

I'm not sure what the `timeInterval` parameter represents in your formatter resolver function:

```ts
function getFormatterByTimeInterval (timeInterval: number) {/* ... */}
```

but I'll ignore that for now. With that out of the way, let's look at the conditionals:

```ts
export const getFormatterByTimeInterval = (timeInterval: number) => {
  // This formats as time and date information
  if (timeInterval > 240) {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.DAY_HOUR_PERIOD;
  }
  // This formats as time-only information
  // Also, this will never match because any `timeInterval` value which is
  // greater than 480 is also greater than 240, so the first conditional above
  // will match and return before reaching this one
  else if (timeInterval > 480) {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.HOUR_PERIOD;
  }
  // Shorter than either of the above
  // This formats as date-only information
  else {
    return TIME_FORMATTER.DAY;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how your program is supposed to work, but that doesn't seem like the intended behavior to me.

---

In regard to your question of conversion:

The `Luxon` equivalent for instantiation of a `DateTime` from a milliseconds `number` type is [`DateTime.fromMillis()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefrommillis). (You don't need to worry about using the `local` method because luxon uses your system's local timezone by default.)

In regard to the equivalent formatting options, they would be:

| [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) | [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens) |
| --- | --- |
| `hh:mm` | `hh:mm` |
| `M/DD` | `L/dd` |
| `hh:mm A` | `hh:mm a` |
| `hh:mm A M/DD` | `hh:mm a L/dd` |
| `HH:mm:ss` | `HH:mm:ss` |

Expressed as code, it looks like this:

```ts
import {DateTime} from 'luxon';

export const TIME_FORMATTER = {
  HOUR: (millis: number) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm'),
  DAY: (millis: number) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('L/dd'),
  HOUR_PERIOD: (millis: number) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm a'),
  DAY_HOUR_PERIOD: (millis: number) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm a L/dd'),
  SEC: (millis: number) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('HH:mm:ss'),
};
```

Then, a small refactor of your resolver:

```ts
type FormatterFn = (millis: number) => string;

export const getFormatterByTimeInterval = (timeInterval: number): FormatterFn => {
  let key: keyof typeof TIME_FORMATTER;
  // I'm still not sure about these conditionals,
  // but this order matches longest duration first
  if (timeInterval > 480) key = 'HOUR_PERIOD';
  else if (timeInterval > 240) key = 'DAY_HOUR_PERIOD';
  else key = 'DAY';
  return TIME_FORMATTER[key];
};
```

And you can check it like this:

```ts
// The time you asked this question
const millis = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-21T21:02:03Z').toMillis();

// Check each conditional range:
for (const timeInterval of [500, 300, 100]) {
  const formatter = getFormatterByTimeInterval(timeInterval);
  console.log(formatter(millis));
}
```

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=29&ssc=48&pln=29&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCIEMYFMAqp0F84BmUEIcA5ADYCuAHhAHZkDcAsAFDvo2SxwDGDAM7xMASQCyAUQD6AMQDyAJXEBBTJkmK4AXkTs4cABLyAqooBccABQhgFCsEGX6VEACN0UAJQ6AfHFQMbBB0ADoiEnE7B0EbaMcvUJgIWWgQNCsyAAss8xAQMi8AGn0AlQBNSzj7R2dXD28-ALQsHHDiECia2NtuxOTUqHSYTIAZAHoAE0nCkrYDYzNpAAVNUXkkKt6YuvdPH21-QNaQ9sj4nov+lLSM7Nz8uBRZ0qQK6UXFFbWNrYvdhoHI4tYJhCKdC7VGLXQbDTI5PKkFBwCbTF7zOAAZUkAGE-t0AfsmsdQWcId0oQkkjchndDIZEeZBIJ0bhWBw2DAAJ5gdBwWFoDBQWT0HTWba1OAuPaNQ5wYRQYD0ADm7M43Gg8AE9GEcGV6BgApgQoAQlzQaJ6EKAG4oChiqwwHCWm12wneSxGoUipoIUoUA1wADW6C5lhDXIgBDg3N5UbgYikciUqnUmnZBnG4zgojIpGE0SlEHggioUD5KDcECo8BgWXQgj52smwCdDDtgjmmezbhrMayjjg0Emnjgwz49cEcAoDH1usmZbQwAYhGAUGEpWA0cdzqtnlt9v8ABYABwABh8EbFZE+30U6yQzFK6AojbgW+sTpCLv3drg-gAJiPC9g1Da83nKD5TC+VZ7w2J8MRfN8r10MgIIQgxyxgMtRUTGQFGUNQNEUABtCMAF12TZdh2CzBN6xjHA4EjKgnkEENJn7QcAEcqAbNt6HYbVdQlKddBJNpwVETF5EyACzwAgCAFozwAZiUgCAEZMC08wFL01SAC1CmpLoYisLw1TYOicXrPggzgdAUAnfgGBbAS-ygFAVXQcx2AIaBrGE2td1de14xIgBWM8zyKOBVJiuLNJi8ifD9DFgsIW5jVHXR9UNbLTXNULfwoHdvz3KAD0s0phIgANQhnZVyvQH8qrtOKAtpHKoEpQQvBqthcHYIA)

Demo of compiled JavaScript from the TS playground link:

```html
<script type="module">

import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@2.3.1/src/luxon.js';

export const TIME_FORMATTER = {
    HOUR: (millis) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm'),
    DAY: (millis) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('L/dd'),
    HOUR_PERIOD: (millis) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm a'),
    DAY_HOUR_PERIOD: (millis) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('hh:mm a L/dd'),
    SEC: (millis) => DateTime.fromMillis(millis).toFormat('HH:mm:ss'),
};
export const getFormatterByTimeInterval = (timeInterval) => {
    let key;
    // I'm still not sure about these conditionals,
    // but this order matches longest duration first
    if (timeInterval > 480)
        key = 'HOUR_PERIOD';
    else if (timeInterval > 240)
        key = 'DAY_HOUR_PERIOD';
    else
        key = 'DAY';
    return TIME_FORMATTER[key];
};
// The time you asked this question
const millis = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-21T21:02:03Z').toMillis();
// Check each conditional range:
for (const timeInterval of [500, 300, 100]) {
    const formatter = getFormatterByTimeInterval(timeInterval);
    console.log(timeInterval, formatter(millis));
}

</script>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks. Yeah, I had a typo on the first conditional which should be fixed now

Comment: @XueXu I'm curious: what is `timeInterval`?